# Java lists and class inheritance

Tags: java, list, inheritance, arraylist

```
List <Person> pers = new ArrayList<Person>();

pers.add(new Women("something1"));
pers.add(new Women("something2"));

pers.add(new Men("something1"));
pers.add(new Men("something2"));

System.out.println(pers); // prints everything
```

The classes Women and Men extend Person. After I store the data in my list how do I print only the Women or only the Men? Also how do I access attributes from the Women and Men?

With 2 lists works fine but I'm having trouble when I only have to use one list.

Comment: You could try using `instanceof` operator, but that usually means that your design is flawed. Why do you want to create only one list of peers? What is wrong with solution using two separate lists?

Comment: Well, if you need to distinguish men from women, you shouldn't store them in the same list.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `instanceof` keyword.

```
for(Person person : pers){
    if(person instanceof Women){
        System.out.println("I am a woman");
        int height = person.getHeight();
    }
    else if(person instanceof Men){
        System.out.println("I am a Man");
        int weight = person.getWeight();
    }
}
```

Once you know what type of object the person is, you can call any public variables/getters/setters on that object.

Comment: Thanks , that helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Object.getClass() will return the type of the object